# Demonstration of hyperbola in polar coordinates

Tags: conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions, hyperbolic-equations

I'm working on Matlab and I have the parameters a,b and c of a hyperbola. I'm working on polar coordinates because an Matlab example did so. I'm trying to get a matrix $2 \times N$  where each column is a set of (x,y) points of a hyperbola. The problem is that I have the resulting expressions but I have to demonstrate them.

The expressions given to create a hyperbola centered at (h,k) from a Matlab example are the following:

$x = a·\cosh(\mu)·\cos(\phi) - b·\sinh(\mu)·\sin(\phi) + h$

$y = a·\cosh(\mu)·\sin(\phi) - b·\sinh(\mu)·\cos(\phi) + k$

where $\phi$ is the angle when getting the polar vector between the two foci.

Considering a hyperbola centered in $(0,0)$  with foci in $[-100 0]$ and $[100 0]$, the parameters $a,b$ and $c$ of the hyperbola are variable but I get the polar coordinates of the hyperbola:

$\rho = 200$

$\phi = 0$

$\mu$ is an array to evaluate a part of the hyperbola

$\mu = [-2, -1.99, -1.98, .... 0, ... 1.98, 1.99, 2.00]$

Then the previous equations become as follows and evaluating them for all $\mu$ vector it provides the desired matrix of pairs (x,y) creating an hyperbola:

$x = a·\cosh(\mu)$

$y = b·\sinh(\mu)$

**THE PROBLEM** is that:

I'm trying to demonstrate how I can get the above mentioned expressions from the standard hyperbola equation:

$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

where the center is in $(h,k)$ to the expressions above mentioned considering that $(h,k) = (0,0)$. I don't know how to make appear a $\cosh(\mu)$ and a $sinh(\mu)$ in the expressions. I don't understand how to include the $\mu$ angle inside this equation.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you know identity cosh^2-sinh^2=1?

Comment: @coffeemath yes but after some attemps to use it I have not been able to

Comment: You have formulas for x and y right before you write "THE PROBLEM is that:". And your formula after h=k=0 is x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1. Just plug in your x and y formulas into this.

Comment: @coffeemath but I have to demonstrate them from the regular expression of the hyperbole

Comment: One way is to use injectivity of sinh, to justify substition of that for one of the variables, Then solve for the other and use the identity I mention to conclude the other variable is +/- cosh, and the choice of + or - is irrelevant since it gets squared.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: the parameterization you seek implies$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=\cos^2\phi+\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\sinh^2\mu-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\cosh^2\mu\right)\sin^2\phi+\frac{a^2-b^2}{2ab}\sinh2\mu\sinh2\phi.$$You'll need a suitable linear transformation to make any of this look like a familiar expression for a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

$x = a·\cosh(\mu)·\cos(\phi) - b·\sinh(\mu)·\sin(\phi) + h$

$y = a·\cosh(\mu)·\sin(\phi) + b·\sinh(\mu)·\cos(\phi) + k$

If $ r = [x, y]^T$ , and the center $C = (h, k) $, and the rotation matrix $R$ is given by,

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi && - \sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) && \cos(\phi) \end{bmatrix} $

and the vector

$ u = [ \cosh(\mu) , \sinh(\mu) ]^T $

then

$ r - C = R D u $

where $ D = \operatorname{diag} \{ a , b \}$

So that

$ u = D^{-1} R^T (r - C) \tag{1} $

Now since $\cosh^2(\mu) - \sinh^2(\mu) = 1 $, then

$ u^T Q_0 u = 1 \tag{2}$

where $Q_0 = \operatorname{diag} \{ 1 , -1 \} $

Using $(1)$ in $(2)$, gives the equation as

$ (r - C)^T R D^{-1} Q_0 D^{-1} R^T (r - C) = 1 \tag{3} $

But

$ Q' = D^{-1} Q_0 D^{-1} = \operatorname{diag} \{ \dfrac{1}{a^2}, -\dfrac{1}{b^2} \} $

So $(3)$ is the rotated version of the standard equation which is

$ (r - C)^T  Q' (r - C) = 1 \tag{4}$